# Use of hyphen instead of slash in hook_menu

Tags: 6, routes

For SEO purpose, I need to use hyphens instead of slashes in a URL defined in `hook_menu`, here's an example :

```
$items['mypath-%'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'mypath_render',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'access arguments' => array('access_content'),
);
```

Apparently Drupal doesn't support it natively. Is there a way to make it work ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would never do this just for the sake of SEO personally, I believe the workaround is to use both [hook_url_inbound_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7)() and [hook_url_outbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7). By using these hooks you can change any URL displayed by the site to replace slashes with the hyphen, and then back again when Drupal processes the page after the user has clicked the URL. That way you can still use slashes in your hook_menu(), but it would show as hyphens in your site.

I'm not sure there is any other way.

**Oh dear, I just realised the question was for Drupal 6, my apologies.**

I think for Drupal 6, using [custom_url_rewrite_inbound()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/custom_url_rewrite_inbound/6) and [custom_url_rewrite_outbound()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/custom_url_rewrite_outbound/6) could be used instead.

Comment: I'm working on a site which use hyphen-only URLs so I don't really have a choice. Anyway, I'm gonna give it a try and see if it works ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've done a similar thing using Drupal 7 and it works well. Not tried it with those Drupal 6 functions but they should do the same thing, though they are not hooks, so they should go in the settings.php file. Good luck.

Comment: Works like a charm, I thank you dearly for the time you made me save by not having to dive into the depths of the Drupal API.